# how to make menu left li background dissapear?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu on a site.
It has a divider on the right of the li, this is set as a background.
When you hover over this it disappears and the link is highlighted.

What i also want is the background of the li on the left to also disappear, how can i do this?

```
    .menu-link ul li    
{
    text-decoration:none;
    float:left;
    background: url(/Content/img/border-line-inside.png) no-repeat right;
}

.menu-link ul li a {
    color:#fff;
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    line-height:40px;
    display: block;
    width:128px;
    text-align:center;
}

.menu-link a:hover{
    background:url(../img/menu-nav-hov.png) repeat-x;
    cursor:pointer; 
}
```

im guessing i might need to use jquery?

Comment: It would be easier for us if you made a jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's not possible to select parent element, nor previous siblings in CSS, you'll need jQuery indeed.

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mvYHB/) might get you in the right direction. (jQuery code might be improved, I'm no expert).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').hover(function() {
        $(this).parent().prev().css('background','none');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).parent().prev().css('background','url(http://placekitten.com/10/20) no-repeat right');
    })
})
```